# React Native - Adding margin: 1 in Camera Roll

Tags: react-native, stylesheet, camera-roll

How to add `margin: 1` perfectly in my Camera Roll? Because when I add `margin: 1` in my `<Image .../>` the order will not be in correct order.

The result I want is like in the Instagram. There's no margin in the Left and Right Side, right?

Just like this Image:

[image]

Here are my Codes:

```
render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {/* <SelectedImage source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}}/> */}
    <Image source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} style={styles.image}/>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {this.state.photos.map((photos, index) => {
        return(
          <TouchableHighlight 
            style={{opacity: index === this.state.index ? .5 : 1}}
            onPress={() => this.setState({pickedImage: photos.node.image.uri})}
            key={index}
            underlayColor='transparent'
          >
            <Image
              style={{width: width / 3, height: width /3}}
              source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
              resizeMode='cover'
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
); 
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
 height: '100%',
 width: '100%',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 alignItems: 'center',
 backgroundColor: 'white'
},
scrollView: {
 flexWrap: 'wrap',
 flexDirection: 'row'
},
scrollViewContainer: {
 flex: 1,
 flexDirection: 'row',
},
 image: {
 width: '100%',
 height: 300,
 backgroundColor: 'black'
}
});
```

This is the Result on my own: (Dont't bother of the Black Border I just didn't crop perfectly and I have just 6 Photos in my Android Emulator).

[image]

Answer Suggested:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.getPhotos();
this.rightButtonIcon();
requestExternalStoragePermission();

photoFilter = () => {
  var arr = this.state.photos;
  var number = 0;
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    switch(number) {
      case 0: 
        number = 1;
        item.position="left"
      break;
      case 1:
        number = 2;
        item.position="center"
      break;
      case 2: 
        number = 0;
        item.position="right"
      break;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  })
  this.setState({photos: arr})
}
};

 imageStylePositionCalc = (pos) =>{
  if(pos==="left") return {marginRight:1,marginBottom:1}
  if(pos==="center") return {marginRight:1,marginBottom:1}
  if(pos==="right") return {marginBottom:1}
 }

  render() {
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {/* <SelectedImage source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}}/> */}
    <Image source={{uri: this.state.pickedImage}} style={styles.image}/>
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollView} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
      {this.state.photos.map((photos, index) => {
        return(
          <TouchableHighlight 
            style={{opacity: index === this.state.index ? .5 : 1}}
            onPress={() => this.setState({pickedImage: photos.node.image.uri})}
            key={index}
            underlayColor='transparent'
          >
            <Image
              style={[{width: width / 3, height: width /3}, this.imageStylePositionCalc(photos.position)]}
              source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
              resizeMode='cover'
            />
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
); 
}
}
```

This is the another Problem, the margin: 1 taking over the full width of the screen and there is no margin in the 2nd row:

[image]

Comment: Did you try adding `borderColor:"#fff"` to the image (or the `touchableOpacity`)?

Comment: Nope, i haven't tried it yet.

Comment: As I mentioned, I do not want the 1st column to have a margin in the Left Side, and the 3rd column I do not want margin in the Right Side.

Comment: How are you rendering your images? are there 2 per row or could they have random dimensions as the image you posted?

Comment: What is the current image looking like? Please show me the result screen.

Comment: @Auticcat no, I use Dimensions to get Width Screen and Divide it to 3 to get 3 column.

Comment: @hongdevelop already added it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing the map, I would suggest to go trough every part of the array and add a value that says if it will be placed into the right, left or center.
Something like:

```
photoFilter=()=>{
   var arr=this.state.photos;
   var number=0;
   arr.forEach((item)=>{
      switch (number){
         case 0: 
            number=1;
            item.position="left"
            break;  
         case 1: 
            number=2;
            item.position="center"
            break;  
         case 2: 
            number=0;
            item.position="right"
            break; 
         default:
            return null 
      }
  })
this.setState({photos:arr})
}
```

then, when rendering the image:

```
<Image
style={[{width: width / 3, height: width /3},this.imageStylePositionCalc(item.position)]}
source={{ uri: photos.node.image.uri }}
resizeMode="cover"
/>
```

then add a function:

```
imageStylePositionCalc=(pos)=>{
  if(pos==="left") return {marginRight:1,marginBottom:1}
  if(pos==="center") return {marginRight:1,marginBottom:1}
  if(pos==="right") return {marginBottom:1}
}
```

This may not be the best answer but should work

UPDATE:
The problem is that you are defining the photoFilter function inside the didMount.

What i meant when i said to call it inside componentDidMount was:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.getPhotos();
this.rightButtonIcon();
requestExternalStoragePermission();
this.photoFilter
}

photoFilter = () => {
      var arr = this.state.photos;
      var number = 0;
      arr.forEach((item) => {
        switch(number) {
          case 0: 
            number = 1;
            item.position="left"
          break;
          case 1:
            number = 2;
            item.position="center"
          break;
          case 2: 
            number = 0;
            item.position="right"
          break;
          default:
            return null;
        }
      })
      this.setState({photos: arr})
    }
```

Comment: It gives me error "Can't find variable: item", and where I should pass the `photoFilter()` function?

Comment: You can put it inside your componentDidMount function. Change item `item` to `photos`

Comment: I think nothing happens?

Comment: Do you mean the `arr.forEach(item)` to `arr.forEach(photos)`?

Comment: I mean the one inside the <Image> render when you set the style when you call imageStylePositionCalc()

Comment: Can you update the code with the changes i suggested?

Comment: Okay ill add to my Question

Comment: Done. Under "Answer Suggested"

Comment: Forgot to make it call the function, do this.photoFilter()

Comment: Are the styles at least getting applied? is imageStylePositionCalc returning something? if you try to add under `if(pos==="right") return {marginBottom:1}` another return without condition? like `return {marginLeft:1}` just to see if something changes? maybe the state is not updating

Comment: It is really not working. I mean the styles doesn't apply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196314/discussion-between-auticcat-and-liza-catherine-ombyaw).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for your problem, which may although not be the best one because I'm not sure how to get rid of the upper and downer most margin, but whatever.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    scrollView: {
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between', // This one is new
        marginHorizontal: -3 // This one is new
    },
    scrollViewContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row'
    },
    image: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 300,
        backgroundColor: 'black'
    }
});

/* Rest of the code stays the same, only the image style gets changed to the follwoing */

<Image
    style={{
        width: width / 3,
        height: width / 3,
        margin: 1
    }}
    source={{ uri: photos.node.image.uri }}
    resizeMode="cover"
/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't go to the Design I want haha. Anyways, thanks for trying.