# React Native - Changing the Style to borderColor instead of margin

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to change the style in my App. This code only works for `marginLeft` or `marginRight` but in `borderColor` doesn't work. What should I change to my codes in order `borderColor` make work in my code?

I have also question about this and it already answered, the problem is that the person who provides the answer in this question is no longer replying. So I decided to ask a related question again. Thank you.

Link: [React Native - Adding margin: 1 in Camera Roll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56971432/react-native-adding-margin-1-in-camera-roll)

This is the code: (This only works for `margins`)

```
onNavigatorEvent = event => {
if (event.type === "ScreenChangedEvent") {
  if (event.id === "didAppear") {
    this.photoFilter();
  }
}}

photoFilter = () => {
var arr= this.state.photos;
var number=0;
arr.forEach((item)=>{
  switch (number){
    case 0: 
      number=1;
      item.position="left"
    break;  
    case 1: 
      number=2;
      item.position="center"
    break;  
    case 2: 
      number=0;
      item.position="right"
      break; 
    default:
      return null 
  }
})
this.setState({photos:arr})
};

imageStylePositionCalc = (pos) =>{
 if(pos==="left") return {borderRightWidth:1, borderBottomWidth:1, borderColor: '#fff'}
 if(pos==="center") return {borderRightWidth:1, borderBottomWidth:1, borderColor: '#fff'}
 if(pos==="right") return {borderBottomWidth:1, borderColor: '#fff'}
};

<Image
    style={[{width: width / 3, height: width /3}, this.imageStylePositionCalc(photos.position)]}
    source={{uri: photos.node.image.uri}}
    resizeMode='cover'
/>
```